# Java - Resize the table based on the column resizing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` with 2 columns, and what I try to achieve is the following:
If the value of a cell from the first column does not fit inside the cell, then you see the 3 ending dots. In such a case I want to resize the column as well as the table, so that the long value fits, in order not to change the width of the second column. Think about it as the expansion of the first column to the left.

Sample code:

```
/**
 * Main.
 * 
 * @param args arguments.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

  String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
    "Last Name"};
  Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy Lathy Alberta 1234567890 11 12 13 14", "Smith"},
    {"John", "Doe"},
    {"Sue", "Black"},
    {"Jane", "White"},
    {"Joe", "Brown"}
  };


  // Create the table based on data and column names
  JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
  // Set an initial size and add it to the main panel
  table.setSize(300, 300);
  panel.add(table);

  // Compute the width of the first column, based on the longest value
  int width = 0, row = 0;
  for (row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
      TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, 0);
      Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, 0);
      width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);
  }

  // Compute the value to be added to the width of the table
  int initialWidth = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getPreferredWidth();
  int delta = width - initialWidth;
  // Try to resize the table and the first column
  table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(table.getPreferredSize().width + delta, table.getHeight()));
  table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(width);

  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
  panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  panel.setPreferredSize(table.getPreferredSize());
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setLocation(800, 300);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

What happens is this:

[image]

Comment: `JTable` really should be wrapped in a `JScrollPane`, see [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems:

You set the layout manager of your panel twice, first to a GridBagLayout and then to a BorderLayout. The layout manager should be set once BEFORE you start adding components to the panel.

```
width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);
```

The preferred width will be too small because the table also includes the intercell spacing amount in the column width. For a simple solution you can use:

```
width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width + 1, width);
```

You can check out [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) for the more general code I use to adjust the column width.

```
// Compute the value to be added to the width of the table
//  int initialWidth = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getPreferredWidth();
//  int delta = width - initialWidth;
// Try to resize the table and the first column
//  table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(table.getPreferredSize().width + delta, table.getHeight()));
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(width);
```

Don't attempt to play with the preferred width of the table. Just set the width of the TableColumn and let the table calculate its own width.